# how to calculate $\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}{\frac{1}{1+\cos ^2x}\rm{dx}}=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{1+\cos ^2x}\rm{dx}+\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}{\frac{1}{1+\cos ^2x}\rm{dx}}}
$$
I want to split this integral,$
\int_{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{3\pi }{4}}{\frac{1}{1+\cos ^2x}\rm{dx}}
$
 but I don't know how to calculate the two integrals after splitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible, maybe more convenient way is as follows:

- First shift the integral using $x=\frac{\pi}{2} + u$:
  $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}= \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{du}{1+\sin^2u}= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{du}{1+\sin^2u}$$
- Now, use $t=\tan u$ and note that $\sin^2u = \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$:

$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{du}{1+\sin^2u}=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1+2t^2}= \sqrt 2\arctan(\sqrt 2)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use in the second integral the substitution $x=\pi-u$ to see that both integrals are equal. Then proceed with substitution $x=\arctan u$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-Use first $\cos^2(x)=\dfrac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$; second $\cos(2x)=\dfrac{1-\tan(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$ so you arrive to
$$\int\dfrac{d(\tan(x))}{\tan^2(x)+2}=\int\dfrac{du}{u^2+2}$$ you get finally
$$\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt2}\right)\right]_{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}^{\dfrac{3\pi}{4}}$$

Comment: Observe that your result is negative whereas the integrand is strictly positive.